# Python: Calling a function called read_min_max

Tags: python

I am very new to coding. I need to convert a c++ program "guess that number" to python and I am stuck on one area. Any help would be much appreciated.

If the user enters anything outside the range of 1 to 100, they should receive a message that says "Please enter a number between 1 and 100.
I have this within a function called read_min_max but I am having errors when I call this function.

This is the function

```
def read_min_max(prompt, min, max):
    result = read_integer(prompt)
    while (result < min or result > max ):
        print("Please enter a number between ", + (min), + " and ", + (max))
        result = read_integer(prompt)
    return result
```

This is how I call this function:

```
number_guessed = read_min_max("Please enter a valid number: ", 1 , 100)
```

This is the error

```
line 16, in read_min_max
    print("Please enter a number between ", + (min), + " and ", + (max))
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

Comment: What is not clear about the error message?

Comment: Try to wrap min and max in str(), to let python know it's strings or take a look at https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you use both commas and pluses to print what you want to print. You could solve it by either removing the commas and making `min` and `max` strings, or remove the pluses and the brackets around `min` and `max`

So either:

```
def read_min_max(prompt, min, max):
    result = read_integer(prompt)
    while (result < min or result > max ):
        print("Please enter a number between ", min, " and ", max)
        result = read_integer(prompt)
    return result
```

or:

```
def read_min_max(prompt, min, max):
    result = read_integer(prompt)
    while (result < min or result > max ):
        print("Please enter a number between " + str(min) + " and " + str(max))
        result = read_integer(prompt)
    return result
```

Comment: I was thinking i was entering min and max wrong when i called it rather than the function itself. Really appreciate your help

Comment: Great that it works, would be great if you accepted it as the right answer if it helped ;)

Comment: Apologies that I hadn't approved it @Rein K. First time posting and didn't realise I had to do this. Will do in future. Thanks again.